# Can I force a dwarf to become sane?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In Dwarf Fortress, is there a DFHack command or can raws be edited to remove insanity from a Dwarf?

Comment: The default mental state of a dwarf is madness. Sanity is a temporary condition - a PRIVILEGE you have to EARN!

Comment: But... where's the fun in that?

Comment: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/images/4/40/FunComic.png
 Fun

Comment: I remember messing with this at some point... I think it was possible with DFHack, but it was rather complex, and I don't remember the details.  Someone might have written a script to do this.  In any case, raw editing won't do it; DFHack is your only chance.

Comment: Just lock the workshop he occupies and have your military ready for some training.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think the resurrection reaction in Masterwork DF also cured the dwarf of insanity - so perhaps it is possible with raws alone.

Answer (score 8):

Short Answer: No. 
Dwarves that go insane will not calm down. 
Long answer: Using the lua console should do the trick with dfhack.

```
dfhack.gui.getSelectedUnit().mood = df.mood_type.None
```

Comment: This question is about hacking the game to make the dwarf sane.  It is possible, it's just hard to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Not necessarily "hacking" the game. I wouldn't consider changing the raws to be memory editing.

Comment: Edited to reflect dfhack.

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: This looks right now (changed my downvote to an upvote), but I thought it was more complex than this.  Has anyone verified that the dwarf stays sane (i.e. doesn't revert to crazy at the start of the next month)?

Comment: I'm unable to as I don't have any saves on hand to test with.